# Can i make an Obect property call a function

Tags: javascript, object

Can I call a function like this in an object? I tried something like this and it seems to be not working. I see that I can put the function in the object. I am more interested to tell which function should be called.

```js
   

function runFunc() {
  console.log("hello");
}
obj = { func: runFunc() };

obj.func;
```

Comment: You're missing the parentheses: `obj.func();`

Comment: @Quentin No, they are asking how to execute a function assigned to a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but your syntax is a bit off. When you create a property that is assigned to the function, you don't add `()` because that will invoke the function.

Later, when you are ready to invoke the function stored in the property, you do use `()` to can call the function as a "method" of the object.

The main point being that in JavaScript, we can ***refer*** to functions by just saying their name and we can ***invoke*** functions by saying their name followed by parenthesis.

```js
function runFunc(){
  console.log("hello");
}

// Create new object and assign the function to a property
obj= { func: runFunc };  // <-- No parenthesis after function name here

obj.func(); // Call function as a "method" of the object

// Or, combine the above and create the property and assign the function at once
// Notice here that the function is anonymous. Adding a name to it won't throw
// an error, but the name is useless since it will be stored under the name of 
// the object property anyway.
obj.otherFunc = function(){ console.log("Hello from other function! ") };

obj.otherFunc(); // <-- Here, we use parenthesis because we want to call the function
```

Comment: I think I have solved it.  var a=function runFunc(){console.log("Hello")};obj={func:a}obj.a();

Comment: @user1894606 You wouldn't name the function (runFunc) when assigning it to `a`. You would just assign an anonymous function to `a` in that scenario.

Comment: @user1894606 I have updated the answer to be more closely matched to the pattern you are using and added some more explanation.